# Cakephp 3 Appending args variable in all pagination links

Tags: php, cakephp, args, paginator

I am using CakePHP V3.5.10

Once I cake bake my code any paginator works because is appending this `args` 
a variable that looks like this:

`domain.com/admin/categories?args=&page=3`

So when I `var_dump` it I get this : `var_dump($this->request->params);`

```
array(9) {
    ["controller"]=>
    string(10) "Categories"
        ["pass"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["action"]=>
    string(5) "index"
        ["prefix"]=>
    string(5) "admin"
        ["plugin"]=>
    NULL
        ["_matchedRoute"]=>
    string(18) "/admin/:controller"
        ["?"]=>
    array(1) {
        ["args"]=>
        string(0) ""
    }
    ["_ext"]=>
    NULL
        ["isAjax"]=>
    bool(false)
}
```

if you can see the place where normally should be `"page"` is `"args"` instead
so I check a diff application of mine and how normally should look is like this:

Healthy URL: `domain.com/admin/categories?page=3`

```
array(9) {
    ["controller"]=>
    string(10) "Categories"
        ["pass"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["action"]=>
    string(5) "index"
        ["prefix"]=>
    string(5) "admin"
        ["plugin"]=>
    NULL
        ["_matchedRoute"]=>
    string(18) "/admin/:controller"
        ["?"]=>
    array(1) {
        ["page"]=>
        string(1) "2"
    }
    ["_ext"]=>
    NULL
        ["isAjax"]=>
    bool(false)
}
```

As you can see here I have

```
array(1) {
   ["page"]=>
   string(1) "2"
```

So that is why paginator doesn't work because can't read the `?page` plus is passing this `?args` that is empty... but what is not known is why paginator will behave in this way? and what to do to make it work?

If is there someone could help with this I'll be really thankful. I've been comparing even codes of the paginator and certainly no idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

OK if you find this error is because of the way the data is being passing

Ex:  `?page=1&sort=name&direction:asc` is not a CakePHP way of handling params.

A right format url in cake should be nice looking like this:  `domain.com/2/name/asc`

The way I end it up passing the params in `routes.php`:

```
$routes->connect('/productoptions/:page/:sort/:direction', ['controller' => 'Productoptions', 'action' => 'index'], ['param' => ['page'], 'param2' => ['sort'], 'param3' => ['direction'] ]);
```

So I can use `$this->request->params['page]` , `$this->request->params['direction]` etc...

In this way, I use CakePHP way of passing and handling params instead of `$_GET`